# Imposing ul li menu items

Tags: positioning, css

I want to make an `ul li` menu and I want to place each li element over previous one.

I don't know if I can explain with words what I mean, so I've made an image showing desired effect:
[image]

How can I do this using plain CSS? Is it possible, or I must use javascript?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    position: relative;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 225px;
    height: 115px;
}
```

but each `li` appears on the same place over previous one.

Comment: Do you want the `li` to appear fully when you hover over it?

Comment: You're not moving your `li` elements... you're moving the `a` elements within them.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to display here? I may have a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negative margin-top to "lift" the li elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/mbe9W/

relevant CSS

```
li { padding:10px; border:1px solid #000; margin-top:-10px; }
li:first-of-type {
 margin-top:0;   
}
​
```

Comment: ohh, that was so simple... It is exaclty what I want, thank you very much :)

Comment: little known trick, that margins can be negative as well as positive :)  Glad it helped.

Comment: Yes, I know, I tried it, but in some invalid way and it didn't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is close:

```
​<ul>
<li><a class="a" href="#">A</a></li>
<li><a class="b" href="#">B</a></li>
<li><a class="c" href="#">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top:30px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    height:50px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height:20px;
    top: -30px;
    left:0;
    width:225px;
    height:115px;

}

.a {
     border:1px solid #ff0000   
}
.b {
     border:1px solid #00ff00  
}

.c {
     border:1px solid #ffff00   
}
​
```